# Validation error while validating inclusion values:Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, testing

I am getting error while testing inclusion in my model validations.Here is my model.rb

```
class Resident < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :room_number,presence: true,uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
  validates :roll_number,presence: true,uniqueness:{case_sensitive: false}
  validates :name, presence: true,length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :hostel,presence: true,inclusion: {in:%w(a b c h pg j frc e g i),message: "%{value} is not a valid hostel"}
end
```

model_test.rb only inclusion test

```
 test "hostel must be valid" do
    if @resident.hostel == %w(a b c h pg j frc e g i)
      assert @resident.valid?
    else
      assert_not @resident.valid?
    end
```

and  I am getting this error

```
     test_should_be_valid#ResidentTest (1455250549.01s)
        Failed assertion, no message given.
        test/models/resident_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:ResidentTest>'
8 tests, 8 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

How can I approach it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try to create an instance of `Resident` in your test at first with either a valid or invalid hostel attribute. Then you should check what you expect.

```
test "hostel must be valid" do
  resident = Resident.create(@valid_attributes.merge({:hostel => 'a'})
  assert resident.valid?
end

test "hostel must be invalid" do
  resident = Resident.create(@valid_attributes.merge({:hostel => 'z'})
  assert_not resident.valid?
end
```

And note: `%w(a b c h pg j frc e g i)` is an array of strings. `if @resident.hostel == %w(a b c h pg j frc e g i)` can't work, because you check a string (I think) against an array.

Comment: what is the function of merge here?
 Is it not right to check  the array of strings in an If statement for assertion,maybe we can compare strings one by one in that if statement

Comment: Merge puts the new hash into the existing @valid_attributes hash. So it adds new key:value pairs or changes values for existing keys: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge

Comment: Your inclusion validation checks wether a single attribute has a/one value of the array, but in your test you look for equality of array == string. The result is false. You could check so: `%w(a b c h pg j frc e g i).include?(resident.hostel)`

Comment: `test "hostel must be valid" do
    if %w(a b c h pg j frc e g i).include?(@resident.hostel)
      assert @resident.valid?
    else
      assert_not @resident.valid?
    end`
still same
`8 tests, 8 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips`

Comment: Just to be clear `model_test.rb` is the same as `resident_test.rb` ?

Comment: `#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007ff277486fe0 @base=#<Resident id: nil, room_number: "EF201", roll_number: "101303110", name: "Example Resident", hostel: "J", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={}>
`

Comment: my mistake: you have to call `@resident.valid?` at first and then `puts @resident.errors.inspect` just before `assert @resident.valid?` to see that there are no other errors than a hostel error.

Comment: I think we have to assert `@resident.hostel` instance with hostel types array. but how to do this ?
`test "name should be present" do
    @resident.name = "     "
    assert_not @resident.valid?
  end` see my presence check validation.. I have check by making `@resident.name="    "` and then asserting it not .I am stuck how to do it here at hostel validations.. I need some idea.

Comment: `#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f801e2b75a0 @base=#<Resident id: nil, room_number: "EF201", roll_number: "101303110", name: "Example Resident", hostel: "J", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:hostel=>["J is not a valid hostel"]}>
` @guitarman

Comment: Yes, but your model has some other validations in place. These could cause some errors and `assert @resident.valid?` will fail. I think what you want to do is: `assert %w(a b c h pg j frc e g i).include?(@resident.hostel)` as the one and only line in your test.

Comment: I have seen,no other validations are causing  failure except this hostel one!
Ahh... I m exhausted .. -_- . Confused also ! I am stuck since 1 hour @guitarman

Comment: Your hostel attribute is upper case: "J" instead of "j"

Comment: Oh f**k.... pfftt....
-_- .. I have been stucked since 1 hour... because of this J. shit... haha
btw thanks !..lol

Comment: ... except the test should still pass, no?  since it's not in the array, it should be invoking `assert_not @resident.valid`

Comment: all is well.. @SteveTurczyn